# jQuery UI calling revert method externally

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have a draggable event set up like such:

```
$(ids.label).draggable({
    containment: ids.wrapper,
    revertDuration: 100,
    revert: function(event) {
        $(this).data("draggable").originalPosition = {
            top:  $(this).data('origionalTop'),
            left: $(this).data('origionalLeft'),
        }
        return !event;
    },
    ...
```

Now, I want to be able to call the revert function externally in another function. How can this be done? Heres kind of what I am trying to do (which currently does not work):

```
$(ids.label).each(function() {
    for(var iter = 0; iter < wrong.length; ++ iter) {
        if($(this).html() == wrong[iter]) {
            // Something along these lines.
            $(this).draggable.revert(); // This is the line in question
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not entirely sure why you would need to call that externally. But this might help:

Instead of:

```
$(this).draggable.revert(); // This is the line in question
```

Try:

```
$(this).draggable('option','revert')();
```

Comment: Ha, yeah I just realized I could do `$(this).data('draggable').options.revert()` also. Thanks!